# 8 processos contendo 3 pais e 2 deles criam 3 filhos em C

Tags: c, processo

Estou com uma dificuldade em resolver um exercício. Tenho que fazer um programa que gere 3  processos pai que por sua vez, dois deles dêem origem à criação de 3 processos filho. E no total, tenho que gerar 8 processos.

O meu problema é que estou a gerar 9 processos e não estou a conseguir perceber porquê. Podem ajudar-me a tentar ver a luz? :)

Obrigado!

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <sys/types.h> 
    #include <unistd.h> 
    
    int main(){
        int x = 2;
        pid_t p = fork(); 
        
        if (p == 0) {
            pid_t w = fork();
            x--;
        }  pid_t t = fork();
             if (t == 0){
                
            x+=3;
        }   else {
            pid_t s = fork(); 
    
        }      
        
        printf("x = %d -> PID = %d -> pai: %d \n", x, getpid(), getppid()); 
    
        sleep(1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Pela sua descrição e pelas minhas contas o total de processos é realmente 9: 3 processos pai: P1, P2 e P3 e 6 processos filhos: P1.1, P1.2, P1.3, P2.1, P2.2 e P2.3.

Comment: Exacto. E eu preciso de ter 8 processos no total, 1 pai que gera três filhos, um dos filhos que gera mais três filhos e mais um filho de filho ou biisneto, para perfazer três pais. Mas já estou muito confundido com o que fiz.

Comment: Pelo que entendi deve ser: Processos: 1, 
1.1, 
1.2, 
1.3, 
1.1.1, 
1.1.2, 
1.1.3 e 
1.1.1.1

Total 8 processos sendo 3 pais: 1 (pai de 1.1), 1.1 (pai de 1.1.1) e 1.1.1 (pai de 1.1.1.1). Processos 1 e 1.1 tem 3 filhos cada.

Comment: Não consigo entender. Não existem processos pai ou processos filho. Todo programa é um processo. Todo processo é filho que algum, ao menos de `init` .Assim seu programa é um processo. Vai gerar 3 processos. Desses 2 vão gerar 3 filhos. Então são dez processos, nove deles filhos de seu programa, 6 deles sem processos filho